# How to add up hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet to track my hours at work and I was wondering how I would go about adding up my total hours. I'm not fussed what format it be in, whether it be HH:MM or as a decimal.

```
...¦.............A.........¦.......B....¦......C.......¦.....D....¦.....E......¦......F   
1.¦..........Date.......¦..Log In.¦..Log Out.¦.Hours.¦.Breaks.¦.Lateness    

2.¦....28/10/2014...¦...08:00.¦..17:00....¦.08:00..¦.01:00..¦..Holiday  

3.¦....29/10/2014...¦...10:41.¦..20:01....¦.08:15..¦.01:00      

4.¦....30/10/2014...¦...Day Off         

5.¦....31/10/2014...¦...08:41.¦..18:05....¦.08:15..¦.01:00
```

The formula I am using to work out my daily hours is  `=INT(((C1-B1)-E1)*96)/96`  (We only get paid for every full 15 minutes we work)

So basically I want a separate cell at the top with my overall weekly hours. I have trawled through countless forums and can't seem to find anything that actually adds up my hours and minutes correctly so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Questions about Microsoft Excel are on-topic at [su].

Comment: Have a look at this example, prepared here on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45039/29140

Answer (score 0):

How about `=INT(((sum(C2:C6)-sum(B2:B6))-sum(E2:E6))*96)/96` Wait, that will add up the odd minutes and may give an extra 15 minutes of pay.

I don't know if this will work, but it is what you should use: `=sum(INT(((C2:C6-B2:B6)-E2:E6)*96)/96)` It should work if you enter it as an array formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (I think that is the right combination, if not it would be <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>). It will have these brackets { } surrounding the formula if it is an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

You are already calculating the "adjusted" daily totals.  All you have to do is add them up.  Say rows 2 through 6 are one work week.  The number you want would simply be:

```
    =SUM(D2:D6)
```